# Inequality with square roots and a difference

Tags: inequality

Prove $$\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}-(a+b+c)\leq\frac{3}{2}$$

My difficulty here is that I don't know a way to handle the difference in the question.

Can Cauchy-Schwarz be used here?

Comment: do you mean this here $$\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}-(a+b+c)\geq\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: is here $a,b,c>0$ given?

Comment: Are $a,b,c\in\mathbb R^+$?

Comment: Maybe rewrite as $$\sqrt u+\sqrt v+\sqrt w-\frac{u+v+w}2\ge \frac32$$

Comment: The inequality seems to be false at $a = b = c = 2$: $\sqrt{2+2} + \sqrt{2+2} + \sqrt{2+2} - (2+2+2) = 0 < 3/2$.

Comment: and i tried to prove it on 4 sheet of papers

Comment: My apologies the conditions in the question are:a,b,c are real numbers, where a+b, b+c and c+a are non-negative

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

in your inequality, $\ge $ must be $\le $.

For every real $x\ge 0 $ we have
$$ -x^2+2x-1\le 0$$
thus
$$-x+2\sqrt {x}-1\le 0$$

$$\implies 2\sqrt {x}-x\le 1$$
$$\implies \sqrt {x}-\frac {x}{2}\le \frac {1}{2} $$
$$\implies \sqrt {a+b}-\frac {a+b}{2}\le \frac {1}{2} .$$

nearly done.

Comment: Thanks. I have inadvertently typed in the incorrect inequality sign.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively using AM-GM inequality: $\sqrt{a+b} = \sqrt{1\cdot (a+b)} \le \dfrac{1+(a+b)}{2}\implies \sqrt{a+b} - \dfrac{a+b}{2} \le \dfrac{1}{2}$. Repeat this application of the AM-GM inequality for the $2$ pairs $(b,c)$, and $(c,a)$ and add up the sought inequality follows.